# Remove one location provider - android

Tags: android, location

I am listening to 2 location providers

> locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
>   500,
>   5,this);              locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
>   500, 5, this);

it is possible somehow remove one listener? For example for one task I just want to use GPS update, and while doing this task I want that NETWORK_PROVIDER will be disabled. It is possible somehow? I tried to do like this :

> locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
>   locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500, 5,this);

But this is not really good, because if GPS had fix, this method is removing it and GPS starts to search satellites again.

Comment: you can use timer for starting NETWORK_PROVIDER after some pre define time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create two different `LocationListener`:

```
private LocationListener gpsListener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location != null){
            // do your work for gps location
        }
    }
};
private LocationListener networkListener = .... // same init as gpsListener
```

And use like:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500, 5, gpsListener); 
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 500, 5, networkListener);
```

Then you can use the approach you are doing, without losing GPS fix.
Instead of:

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(this); 
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500, 5,this);
```

You will use:

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(networkListener);
```

Comment: how I should initialize LocationListeners? Because I am getting null error

Comment: Also when you are using this, you can remove "implements LocationListener" since you will use these two listeners instead.